# Condutive clamp or similar?

Tags: connector, wire

I have a sheet of annodized metal that I need to connect a wire to. In the past I have tried wire glue and soldering but each are really ineffective in their own ways. Soldering is slow and best for one-off projects while wire glue becomes less effective or breaks over time.

What I would really like to try next is some kind of alligator clamp or paper clip or screwhole attached to a clamping mechanism. A wire would go in, I would screw it down, and at the other end there would be a clamp against the piece of annodized metal. Annodized metal is annoying to solder to but still conductive, so this should work ?

The annodized metal is only about ~4mm wide and 1mm thick. So I would really like to find a product category on Digikey or Mouser that is able to fulfill this need.

Comment: "Contacts connector" on Digikey provides some options: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/contacts-leadframe/416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a [foil connector](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-foil-connectors/402) (representative image below). These have integrated spikes meant to puncture a foil shield and provide a good electrical contact to it; I expect they'd work well enough on thin sheet as well.

[image]

Most are designed for permanent installation, crimping directly onto a wire, but if you want to easily connect and disconnect wires, there are some like [this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/51943/A122634-ND/2307349) that have a QC tab to mate with a common, cheap QC terminal that you can crimp onto a wire. Of course, you can also get one of the crimp-on ones and give it a pigtail with whatever connector you want, too.

---

For heavier duty, a [split bolt](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/cables-wires-management/cable-supports-and-fasteners/490?k=split%20bolt) might be an option. If you tap a hole in your sheet, or just use a lock washer, preferably the star type, (to penetrate the insulating oxide layer) and a nut with an unthreaded hole, you should be able to make good contact with a large-gauge wire.

Note that I haven't personally used a split bolt in such an application and don't know how effective it will be. I have only used them to ground chain-link fences, for which they work well, but I don't know how good a contact they would make through the threads, nor do I know how to determine what size nut to use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**The anodic layer is non-conductive.**

To accomplish your task, any method to break thru the anodic layer damages the corrosion resistance by reducing the electrical resistance.

This could be done with a fine-threaded machine screw+star washer+ nut with suitable size to fit the part and sharp edges to cut thru the anodization on both sides.  Available metals are SS, Steel, Brass.

[image]